# Three Number Sum - Finding triplets that sum to target

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, sum

> Write a function that takes in a non-empty array of distinct integers and a target integer.
>
> Your function should find all triplets in the array that sum up to the target sum and return a two-dimensional array of all these triplets.
>
> Each inner array containing a single triplet should have all three of its elements ordered in ascending order

**ATTEMPT**

```
function threeNumberSum(arr, target) {  
    let results = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        let finalT = target - arr[i];    
        let map = {};    

        for (let j = i+1; j < arr.length; j++) { 
            if (map[arr[j]]) { 
                results.push([arr[j], arr[i], map[arr[j]]]);
            } else {
                map[finalT-arr[j]] = arr[j];
            }
        } 
    }

    return results;
}
```

My code is formatted all funny, but right now im not getting any output. Am I missing a console log somewhere or something?

[image]

Comment: please remove funny characters from the code.

Comment: I cleaned your code (removed the \u2028 character) and it works fine

Comment: thank you for fixing, anyone see what im doing wrong here?

Comment: Your code works fine. What is the problem here?

Comment: Add your test code to the question

Comment: @Amir has been added

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you read input wrong.

Pay attention to the last part of question: **How to Read Input that is Used to Test Your Implementation**

You wrote a function that takes the array as first arg and the target integer as the second one. But the input is entered one by one, so your program should read one value at a time from the console input.

Comment: Ok, so, what should i change?

Comment: You should write a program that takes the input in the specified way. i.e one by one. Read the question again and pay attention to the details

Comment: I can understand what it means and what you're saying, i guess im not sure how to do that one by one

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question but to answer the comment question of how to accept an arbitrary list of numbers one at a time instead of in an array you can, in Javascript, use the spread syntax. However, the arbitrary list of arguments must be the last arg.

```js
// Using target first and numbers last
function tripletSum(target, ...numbers) {
  console.log(numbers);
}

tripletSum(7, 1, 2, 3, 4); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

To be able to do this *exactly* with `target` last, you will need to use the `arguments` keyword in Javascript. This would require you key into the last item in the arguments and assume it is the target...

```js
// Not a great way but could work... using arguments
function tripletSum() {
  const numbers = arguments.slice(0, argument.length - 1);
  const target = arguments[arguments.length - 1];
}
```